# Store variable as class name?

Tags: svelte

Is it possible to use a store variable in Svelte as class name?

Tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
export const classNameForSvg = writable('iconWrapper')


<div class={`${$classNameForSvg}`} bind:offsetWidth={width} use:inView>
```

Would be a super simple way of switching between classnames..

Answer (score 2):

You might have forgotten the [`:global()` modifier](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-style)? The template string is not neccessary, simply `class={$classStore}` is enough (the store value is a string), then it works [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/fcb215befa97494fa6623c5964823929?version=3.46.6)

```
<script>
    import {writable} from 'svelte/store'
    const className = writable('class-one')
</script>

<div class={$className} on:click={() => $className = 'class-two'}>
    Div with changing class
</div>

<style>
    :global(.class-one) {
        background: lightblue;
    }
    :global(.class-two) {
        background: lime;
    }
    div {
        padding: 3rem;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: You can drop the writable function. `let className = 'class-one';` and assigning via `on:click={()=>className = 'class-two'}` works

Answer (score 1):

Is 'div' supposed to be a component, not just a normal HTML div? If so, it won't pass onto the component element class unless you specify. I am sure this is the reason as I wouldn't bind anything to DIV unless it is a component. Make sure your component supports:

```
// this is a child component
<script>
...
  let classNames;
  export { classNames as class };
...
</script>
<div class={classNames}>
</div>
```

```
<script>
import {writable} from 'svelte/store'

export const classNameForSvg = writable('iconWrapper')
</script>

// this is the parent view
<MyIconComponent class={$classNameForSvg} bind:offsetWidth={width} use:inView/>
```

If it isn't a component, I am sure attaching what classname it returns will be very much helpful.